# Changing the fontColor of cells when editing

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write an Apps Script that change the font color of a cell when it value changes.

I found a way to to change de fontColor of a range, and add to trigger 'onEdit', but the all range is changing and not the single cells that I've been modify.

Here is my Script :

```
function changeFontColor() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetA1 = ss.getSheetByName('Voltaire');
  var lastRow = sheetA1.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheetA1.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheetA1.getRange(3, 3, lastRow -6, lastColumn);

  
  dataRange.setFontColor('Red');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using the edit event object.**

```
function changeFontColor(e) {

   e.range.setFontColor('Red');

}
```

- On the first line `e` is used to "catch" the edit event object.
- On the "last statement" `e.range` is used instead of `dataRange`.
- All other statements aren't required.

**Using `getActiveRange`** (no edit event object)

```
function changeFontColor() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getActiveRange().setFontColor('Red');

}
```

- On the "last statement" `ss.getActiveRange()` is used instead of `dataRange`.
- Only the first and the last statements are required.

Related

- [postEdit functions getting range](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/135043/88163)

Comment: Thank you @Rubén, I can't manage to make it work tho... I get an error message :
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (ligne 6, fichier "Code")"